# No DNS settings for Parallel Panel

Tags: plesk

I'm completely new to Parallel as i'm helping out someone and I want to change DNS settings to switch MX records.  I don't see DNS settings anywhere, so i searched around and it says to enable DNS zone settings??  Here are screenshots.. there are no DNS settings or DNS zone settings?

[image]
[image]

How do i solve this?  As you can see there are no DNS settings(zone).  The account also has administrator privilege(all privileges), what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to that, the first thing you need to confirm is, whether you have installed DNS server /bind installed in Plesk,

You can check it in Tools & Settings >> Server Components

If you did not find any components for bind, then go ahead and install it from autoinstaller.

To do so either you can proceed with Tools & Settings >>Updates & Upgrades 
or; Login to server as root and run /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/autoinstaller

Answer (score 0):

you need to set dns settings on your domain level where it is registered.
for example, if your domain.com is registered within godaddy then login into the account and set DNS settings there, it could be the IP of your server to the dns.
I think in godaddy acocunt, it is Domains > manage DNS of the domain

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk Panel , You need to access to your domain and click Customize .

After clicking Customize - you need to access to permissions tab and select : 
DNS zone management
(If granted, makes DNS service parameters act as a preset.)

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

Check if dns zone managment is enabled.

*For a certain subscription*
Subscriptions > Desired Subscription Domain > General Tab:Customize > Permissions Tab:DNS zone management
(if changed, subscription lock out of plan updates)

*For entire service plan* (recommended)
Service Plans > Desired Plan > Permissions Tab:DNS zone management
(subscription(s) in plan might be unlocked for syncing settings)

[image]
 Image is common for these two ways in solution (PSA 12.0.18)

**Second Solution**

Caused by bind9 loading failure in combination with a recent upgrade.
The above DNS zone managment checkbox is missing! 
A Plesk package (plesk-dns-bind-driver) depends on bind9. So you should NOT force a remove/purge of bind9 and then install again.
You also might noticed a bind9 loading failure at startup.
(not always affects PSA, but after a recent upgrade, fixing bind9 failure is necessary)
So if suddenly "DNS Settings" replaced with "Whois Information" this is your solution.
**So** `service bind9 restart` fails as expected.
Then check for an apparmor denial

```
# tail /var/log/syslog

...
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/named" 
name="/var/named/run-root/etc/named.conf" pid=4869 comm="named" 
requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=0
...
```

if there is something like above, then edit `etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` and add in
/usr/sbin/named only section

```
/usr/sbin/named{
..
  /var/named/run-root/** rwm,   #add this line
..
}
```

Then please do update && upgrade (you might noticed an `1 not fully installed or removed` again).
After a server restart all works fine for me again!

giannisepp